# How can an equation having ColorDistance function be solved?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, color

I wish to extract the colors on the `L` axis in the `CIELab` color space such that the `CIE2000` distance between a corresponding color and `LABColor[0., 0., 0.]` will be gradually increasing by a factor `0.01`. For example, `{LABColor[0, 0, 0], LABColor[0.01733965, 0, 0], LABColor[0.0344219, 0, 0], LABColor[0.0512525, 0, 0], LABColor[0.0678371, 0, 0], LABColor[0.0841806, 0, 0], LABColor[0.100288, 0, 0]}` are the first few colors in this series. I have got these values by manually checking. However, to automate this, when I tried the following (to get the second element in the series)

```
Solve[ColorDistance[LABColor[0, 0, 0], LABColor[l, 0, 0], 
DistanceFunction -> "CIE2000"] == 0.01, l]
```

I got an error message.

How can I automate this process to complete the series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
f[l_?NumericQ] := 
   ColorDistance[LABColor[0, 0, 0], LABColor[l, 0, 0], DistanceFunction -> "CIE2000"]

FindRoot[f[l] == 0.01, {l, .5}]
(* {l -> 0.0173396} *)
```

`ColorDistance` does not work with symbolic inputs. Write a function that evaluates with numeric inputs only.

`Solve` is meant for exact symbolic computations. Use `FindRoot` instead.

Comment: Perfect. Now I can get the complete list. Thanks.